# How can I find the difference in values by month in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
Date     Value
1/1      10
1/2      10
...
1/31     11
.
.
.
2/1      13
2/2      12
...
2/28     13
.
.
.
3/1      12
3/2      16
...
3/31     16
.
.
.
4/1      14
4/2      14
4/3      14
```

I want to find the difference between the values from the first of each month, and turn it into data that looks like this:

```
January     3        // +3 from Jan 1 to Feb 1
February    -1       // -1 from Feb 1 to March 1
March       2        // + 2 from March 1 to April 1
April
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({FILTER(A1:A, DAY(A1:A)=1), 
    IFNA(QUERY(FILTER(B1:B, DAY(A1:A)=1), "offset 1", )-
               FILTER(B1:B, DAY(A1:A)=1))})
```

[image]